# The title of the property the conversion to string what happens

Tags: javascript

we have such an object.

```
let user = {
  true: 300,
  valueOf(){console.log("1")},
  toString(){console.log("2")}
};
```

what will happen in stages if you write such code.

```
console.log(user[true])
console.log(user[false])
```

how js convert false true to string?

```js
let user = {
  true: 300,
  valueOf() {
    console.log("1")
  },
  toString() {
    console.log("2")
  }
};

console.log(user[true])
console.log(user[false])
```

Comment: Try to get the basics first.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: your object has property true and doesn't have property false, no conversion happens, it just searches for the key and outputs it if found, or return undefined otherwise.

Comment: _how js convert false true to string?_ There is no string convertion happening in your example.

Comment: To get string conversion, you have to convert *the object*, to the value of the key. So `"" + user` will do the implicit conversion to string and `0 + user` will implicitly convert to number. Both will use `valueOf` since it's just asking for the primitive value, not explicitly for a string. `String(user)` will use the `toString()` method as would evaluating `user` in a template literal `\`hello ${user}\``.